# ServiceStack MAX and MIN query

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Being relatively new to ServiceStack, I am not sure how to do this...

I have an object called NextHint which provides a hint to the user.

```
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    public int TimesShown { get; set; }
```

I am trying to find the Hint that has the highest number of votes  (MAX(VoteCount)) and has been least seen (MIN(TimesShown)).  The rationale of the logic is not the point here but rather the SQL mechanics.

My method currently looks like...

```
public object Get(NextHint request)
    {
        Hint hint;
        using (var db = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            //Don't know what to do here!!!
            db.Single<Hint>("MIN(TimesShown) and MAX(VoteCount) group by Id");

            //Update the count of TimesShown 
            hint.TimesShown++;
            db.Update(hint);
        }
        return new NextHintResponse { Title = hint.Title, Body = hint.Body };
    }
```

Could some point me in the right direction?
BTW - i am using MySql but would like the solution to remain generic.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your search requirements. Do you want to get the highest vote count, find all hints with that count, and then select the hit out of those with the lowest times shown?